# My html page contains 3 tables I want horizontal scroll to one of them

Tags: html, css, html-table, horizontal-scrolling, bootstrap-table

Here I want horizontal scroll for table with id "datavaulttable" I have tried with `overflow-x` and `display:block` property but it is not working, while specifying `overflow-x` property I also set width property like `width:200px` still it not working.

---

```
 <body style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 100px">
        <div>
            <table id="tbluserfolder">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button id="addbutton" class="btn"
                            style="background-color: lightgray" onclick="folderInfo()">
                            <img src="/BoardUI/img/plussign.jpg" height="50px" width="50px" />
                            Add Folder
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <table class="foldertable table-bordered" id="datavaulttable" >
                <!-- 
                table-striped 
                <thead>

                    <tr>

                        <th>File</th>

                        <th>Created On</th>

                        <th>Created By</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead> -->

            </table>


            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="fileinfo">


                <thead>

                    <tr>

                        <th>File</th>

                        <th>Created On</th>

                        <th>Created By</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>

            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: bootstrap overflowing of tables work by adding a wrapper with scrolling overflow _around_ the table. [See Docs here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-responsive)

Comment: thank you @haxxxton  i got your point and now its working after adding to div tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> i just added div tag , wrapped table with div
> ```

```
 <div style="overflow-x: scroll; width: 99%"> 
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="datavaulttable">
                    <!-- 
                table-striped 
                <thead>

                    <tr>

                        <th>File</th>

                        <th>Created On</th>

                        <th>Created By</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead> -->

                </table>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="scrollmenu">
```

Your table code comes inside that div with class scroll menu.

Comment: i added overflow-x property to div

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap the by adding class

```
table-responsive
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fb7xLmx2/

`overflow-x:scroll` is working

Comment: posted my answer below working fine for me, thank you for adding information will try yours also